# What does a thick line represents in a ERD diagram?

Tags: database, diagram, erd

For example, the following ERD diagram:

[image]

What does the thick-bordered rectangle means?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It means aggregation between a set of relationship (in the thick-bordered rectangle) and other entities.
Think about the entities in the thick-bordered rectangle as a stand alone entity.
If we want to translate this to tables you will have: patient table, disease table, diagnostic table (which is the relationship table). These 3 tables form the aggregation.
Now these aggregation interacts with treats table and receives table. That means that table receives will have columns: `cocktail_id,diagnostic_id`
and treats table will have: `doctor_id,diagnostic_id`